# need to print the decrypted value separately as well

Tags: python

I am looking to find the decrypted value so it will show all the possible outcomes. And since the key is half the length of message that why it will show the correct value there. But I also want to show that decrypted text at the end as well separately.

```
def brute_force():
    msg = raw_input('Enter your text here: ')

    key = len(msg)/2

    alphabets = 'ABC2&0346_+/*~DEFGHIJK(){";.<.>LMNOPQRST:?UVWXYZ!#$%'
    cipher = ' '

    msg = msg.upper()

    for chars in msg:
        if chars in alphabets:
            sol = alphabets.find(chars)
            sol = sol + key

            if sol >= len(alphabets):
                sol = sol - len(alphabets)

            elif sol < 0:
                sol = sol + len(alphabets)

            cipher = cipher + alphabets[sol]

        else:
            cipher = cipher + chars
    print('Encrypted text {}'.format(cipher))
    decrypt = cipher

    for key in range(len(alphabets)):
        dec_text = ' '

        for alphas in decrypt:
            if alphas in alphabets:
                sol_dec = alphabets.find(alphas)
                sol_dec = sol_dec - key 

                if sol_dec < 0:
                    sol_dec = sol_dec + len(alphabets)

                dec_text = dec_text + alphabets[sol_dec]

            else:
                dec_text = dec_text + alphas

        print('key {} {}'.format(key, dec_text))

    if (dec_text == msg):
        word = dec_text
    else:
        word = 'Couldnt find'


    print('Decrypted text is {}'.format(word))
brute_force()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm interpreting this question as "why does my program always display 'Decrypted text is Couldnt find', even though I can see the decrypted text in the earlier output?". There are three reasons. First, you initialize `cipher` and `dec_test` with a space:

```
cipher = ' '
#...
dec_text = ' '
```

When you should instead initialize them with empty strings. If you don't do this, then all of your decrypted strings will have two spaces at the beginning, and they'll never compare equal to your original message.

```
cipher = ''
#...
dec_text = ''
```

Additionally, this conditional:

```
if (dec_text == msg):
    word = dec_text
else:
    word = 'Couldnt find'
```

Appears *outside* of the `for key in range(len(alphabets))` loop. This means that it executes exactly once, when `dec_text` has whatever value it was given during the 51st iteration of the loop. If you want to compare `msg` against *all* the different values that `dec_text` has, then you need to compare within the loop.

```
word = 'Couldnt find'
for key in range(len(alphabets)):
    dec_text = ''

    for alphas in decrypt:
        if alphas in alphabets:
            sol_dec = alphabets.find(alphas)
            sol_dec = sol_dec - key 

            if sol_dec < 0:
                sol_dec = sol_dec + len(alphabets)

            dec_text = dec_text + alphabets[sol_dec]

        else:
            dec_text = dec_text + alphas

    print('key {} {}'.format(key, dec_text))

    if (dec_text == msg):
        word = dec_text
```

Note that I've completely removed the `else` block, instead unconditionally initializing `word` to `"Couldnt find"` at the beginning. Simply adding the `else` alongside the `if` inside the loop wouldn't have worked, because there's nothing stopping `"Couldnt find"` from overwriting `word` even after it had attained a value in an earlier iteration. This means you would always get "Couldnt find" unless the decrypted text was found in the very last iteration. Having only the `if` without the `else` solves this issue.

Finally, you may want to compare the decrypted text to the original text in a case-insensitive way. Otherwise, you can only match messages that are in all-caps.

```
if (dec_text == msg.upper()):
```

All together, the final program looks like:

```
def brute_force():
    msg = raw_input('Enter your text here: ')

    key = len(msg)/2

    alphabets = 'ABC2&0346_+/*~DEFGHIJK(){";.<.>LMNOPQRST:?UVWXYZ!#$%'
    cipher = ''

    msg = msg.upper()

    for chars in msg:
        if chars in alphabets:
            sol = alphabets.find(chars)
            sol = sol + key

            if sol >= len(alphabets):
                sol = sol - len(alphabets)

            elif sol < 0:
                sol = sol + len(alphabets)

            cipher = cipher + alphabets[sol]

        else:
            cipher = cipher + chars
    print('Encrypted text {}'.format(cipher))
    decrypt = cipher

    word = 'Couldnt find'
    for key in range(len(alphabets)):
        dec_text = ''

        for alphas in decrypt:
            if alphas in alphabets:
                sol_dec = alphabets.find(alphas)
                sol_dec = sol_dec - key 

                if sol_dec < 0:
                    sol_dec = sol_dec + len(alphabets)

                dec_text = dec_text + alphabets[sol_dec]

            else:
                dec_text = dec_text + alphas

        print('key {} {}'.format(key, dec_text))

        if (dec_text == msg):
            word = dec_text


    print('Decrypted text is {}'.format(word))
brute_force()
```

When run, this produces the result:

```
Enter your text here: hello world
Encrypted text )JQQT #TUQI
key 0 )JQQT #TUQI
key 1 (IPPS !S?PH
key 2 KHOOR ZR:OG
key 3 JGNNQ YQTNF
key 4 IFMMP XPSME
key 5 HELLO WORLD
key 6 GD>>N VNQ>~
key 7 F~..M UMP.*
key 8 E*<<L ?LO</
key 9 D/..> :>N.+
key 10 ~+;;. T.M;_
key 11 *_""< S<L"6
key 12 /6{{. R.>{4
key 13 +4)); Q;.)3
key 14 _3((" P"<(0
key 15 60KK{ O{.K&
key 16 4&JJ) N);J2
key 17 32II( M("IC
key 18 0CHHK LK{HB
key 19 &BGGJ >J)GA
key 20 2AFFI .I(F%
key 21 C%EEH <HKE$
key 22 B$DDG .GJD#
key 23 A#~~F ;FI~!
key 24 %!**E "EH*Z
key 25 $Z//D {DG/Y
key 26 #Y++~ )~F+X
key 27 !X__* (*E_W
key 28 ZW66/ K/D6V
key 29 YV44+ J+~4U
key 30 XU33_ I_*3?
key 31 W?006 H6/0:
key 32 V:&&4 G4+&T
key 33 UT223 F3_2S
key 34 ?SCC0 E06CR
key 35 :RBB& D&4BQ
key 36 TQAA2 ~23AP
key 37 SP%%C *C0%O
key 38 RO$$B /B&$N
key 39 QN##A +A2#M
key 40 PM!!% _%C!L
key 41 OLZZ$ 6$BZ>
key 42 N>YY# 4#AY.
key 43 M.XX! 3!%X<
key 44 L<WWZ 0Z$W.
key 45 >.VVY &Y#V;
key 46 .;UUX 2X!U"
key 47 <"??W CWZ?{
key 48 .{::V BVY:)
key 49 ;)TTU AUXT(
key 50 "(SS? %?WSK
key 51 {KRR: $:VRJ
Decrypted text is HELLO WORLD
```

Now it successfully detects the decrypted text.

Comment: dude you were so helpful. thankw so much. GOD bless you. :)